# Trying to calculate the conversion rate of customers who just sign a virtual greeting card to eventually buying a card

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to calculate the conversion rate of customers who sign a virtual greeting card and end up not buying to those who sign and buy. On my site, if a customer signs a greeting card but does not purchase it (either leaves or they save the card for later) this is recorded into our DB under column sign_notification with a 1 and is_paid with a 0. Customers who sign and purchase the greeting card are recorded in their respective columns as 1 and 1. I use the reference email as the unique key for this table as all other customers information are found on other tables.

I'm a complete novice at SQL and here is the query I wrote (please be nice):

```
SELECT COUNT(ref_email) 
FROM canvases WHERE sign_notification = 1 && is_paid = 0 / 
(
SELECT COUNT(ref_email) 
FROM canvases 
WHERE sign_notification = 1 && is_paid = 1);
```

Am I suppose to use SUM instead? Both these queries work separately but I am unsure on how to write a query that correctly divides them.

Comment: @Masao_Terada . . . Sample data and desired results are always helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just:

```
SELECT SUM(is_paid = 1) / COUNT(*)
FROM canvases 
WHERE sign_notification = 1
```

This will give you the conversion rate, ie the number of customers who signed *and* bought divided by the number of customers who signed.

This expression takes advantage of a nice MySQL feature where a true condition is evaluated as `1`; this avois the need for a `CASE` construct.

Comment: This actually worked perfectly. Thank you so much! I made it way more difficult than it needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. Try:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN sign_notification = 1 AND is_paid = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(1) AS PercentPaid
FROM canvases
WHERE sign_notification = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with average:

```
SELECT AVG(is_paid)
FROM canvases
WHERE sign_notification = 1 ;
```

This works because `is_paid` is a number -- either 0 or 1.  The average is the proportion of people who have paid.  (You can use `1 - AVG(is_paid)` to get the people who did not pay.

Comment: Event A is signing a card. Event B is buying one. How do you distinguish between those who buy and then sign, and those who sign and then buy.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . "I'm trying to calculate the conversion rate of customers who sign a virtual greeting card and end up not buying to those who sign and buy."  Based on the sample query, this is stored in a single row with a flag.  That at least is  a reasonable interpretation of the question.

Comment: @Strawberry Great question. The checkout process on the website would require you to fill out the card and sign it before you complete the purchase. So there wouldn't be an instance where you can buy the card then sign it.

Comment: @what if the sequence goes sign - buy - sign - sign -buy. What's the conversion rate, and does the solution above provide it? If so, there's your answer. If not, improve your question!